# ArcGIS constantly shut down by itself

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, tiger, serious-application-error

I am trying to open Census tract data, downloaded from http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-data.html  Every time, I open the file in ArcGIS, the software will return an "serious application error...unable to continue" and close by itself after a few minutes. Does anyone have the same problem, or know how to deal with it?

I have tried different computers, different state's file, and redownlaoded files...

Comment: What version of ArcGIS? Also, what is the direct link to the file(s) in question?

Comment: I am using ArcGIS 10.0. Paul, please use the link above-->select 2007 - 2011 American Community Survey 5-Year Estimates Data Profiles — Geodatabase Format--> select a state. I tried different states, the problem remains.

Comment: Running 10.1 SP1, I was able to open the Louisiana one and perform a field calculation without a fatal crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had that exact problem trying to open the block group geodatabases and the problem seems to be two-fold:

1. The width of the data exceeds a dbf's limitations (which I think is 32,767). This is a problem for the block group geodatabasescthat have 1,877 fields.
2. The geodatabases **that were created using ArcGIS 10.1** have compatibility issues running in other versions (including 10.0).

Possible solutions:

1. When exporting, select specific fields that you want to exclude from being exported so that you don't run into a width problem when the files are being exported from geodatabase to DBF IV format.
2. Find someway to use ArcGIS 10.1?

Comment: Thanks Kotebiya. The problem is bit weird. I had the same problem you described with blockgroup data and fixed it like what you said. But this time, I did not export or do anything; the ArcGIS shut down! Some Census tract file is quite small actually...